patrol develop can not start and attach to Flutter (android) app
I'm trying to use the patrol develop command to use the hot reload functionality. But when I run it, the app is built properly but it never launches on my emulator and I see a warning that says it is not attached to the app yet
❯ patrol develop -t integration_test/initial_test.dart  --device=emulator-5554 --flavor=dev

• Building apk with entrypoint test_bundle.dart...
✓ Completed building apk with entrypoint test_bundle.dart (50.1s)
• Executing tests of apk with entrypoint test_bundle.dart on emulator-5554...
Hot Restart: logs connected
[WARN] Hot Restart: not attached to the app yet

This is my test code
import 'common.dart'; // Copied from an example in patrol's example app, linked below

void main() {

  patrolSetUp(() {
    // Smoke test for https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol/issues/2021
    expect(2 + 2, equals(4));
  });

  patrol('Initial test', ($) async {
    await createApp($);

    await $('Continue with English').tap();
    expect($('Get Started'), findsOneWidget);
    await $('Get Started').tap();
  });
}


I followed setup for android as given in the documentation. I setup flavors as well as I use two flavors in my app. Removing the --flavor flag also doesn't help.
I broke my head trying to figure out the functions used in the code demonstrated in the video given in docs. I then figured out that it uses methods from a file called common.dart that contains some wrapper methods. Using the exact same setup still doesn't help.
